# Plotly graph_objects change font color of only part of the text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I'm trying to make a bar chart in Plotly and want part of the title to have the same color as the bar but not all the text.

This is what I've tried thus far. The print show what I'm hoping to get.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def create_barchart(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df["value"],
        y=df["col_name"],
        orientation="h",
        showlegend=False,
        marker_color='rgb(223,16,103)'
    ))
            
    def rgb(r, g, b):
        """
        RGB text (from @MiloCat's example)
        """
        return f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m"

    pink = rgb(223,16,103)

    reset = "\033[0m" # Important!
    title = f'This is black text {pink} this is a highlight {reset}.'
    print(title)
    
    fig.update_layout(
        title={"text": title},
    )

    fig.show()

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value':[123, 34, 54, 87, 98, 102]})
create_barchart(df)
```

Comment: Hey, I am pretty sure that that coloring code only applies to prints in the console. If you want to change how plotly renders text, you would be better of writing title as a HTML string with what you want

Comment: `fig.update_layout(title_text="This is black text <span style='color:pink'>this is a highlight </span>" )`

Comment: Thank you both!!! that worked a treat. So simple but could not find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting working solution from @HMH1013 and @Lourenco answers

```
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value':[123, 34, 54, 87, 98, 102]})
    
    pink_color='#D51067'
    
    def create_barchart(df):
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=df["value"],
            y=df["col_name"],
            orientation="h",
            showlegend=False,
            marker_color=pink_color
        ))
    
        fig.update_layout(
            title={"text": f'This is black text <span style="color:{pink_color}">this is a highlight</span>.'},
        )
    
        fig.show()
    
    create_barchart(df)
```